# Azure: get SQL data synchronously

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I'm a beginner in Azure / SQL topics. I'm trying to get the objects out of a SQL Azure database which belong to my class objects. Let's say there are objects which correspond with my type `UserPosition` in the SQL Server database.

How can I get them in an easy, synchronous manner? At the moment, performance isn't important. I just want to get the data for learning purposes.

This is my code:

```
    IMobileServiceTable<UserPosition> PositionTable;
    MobileServiceClient client;
    client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);
    PositionTable = client.GetTable<UserPosition>();
    Task<List<UserPosition>> items;
    items = PositionTable.ToListAsync();
    items.Start();
```

I now get an exception:

> Start may not be called for a promise-style-task.

(I translated it from German)

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `async` keyword is great for turning what would be complex thread execution code into code that looks like and programs like it's synchronous.  You can do this by using the await keyword, which as far as your method is concerned will execute as if it were synchronous, but with the benefit that the execution thread will be returned to the pool and reused by the host process while waiting for the dependency to execute.  If you're not interested in the detail of controlling/monitoring the Task itself (and I don't think you are in this example), then replace

```
Task<List<UserPosition>> items;
items = PositionTable.ToListAsync();
items.Start();
```

with

```
List<UserPosition> data = await PositionTable.ToListAsync();
```

And be sure to mark your method as async as well.  This will give you the benefit of asynchronous execution without the hassle of asynchronous programming!

Answer (score 0):

The `Task<List<UserPosition>> items` is already running because `async methods` return always a running `Task<T>`. Remove `items.Start();` and your code will work.

Comment: Ok. Now I don't get any exception. But I don't get any data either. The task now tells me "WaitingForActivation". When I do a "List<UserPosition> allItems = items.Result" at the end, the app hangs there.

Comment: Calling Wait or inspecting the Result property on a task can (and will) cause deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I get my data out of it - or even see if there is dat in my items task?

Comment: Print the result after `.Result`